# Twitter JSON in_reply_to_status_id wrong

Tags: javascript, twitter

Has anybody ever had problems with twitters json .in_reply_to_status_id

It seems to be rounding my last number to 0 everytime. If you run this code it should prompt you the url of where the in reply to message should be, but the last number is always a 0. I am pretty new to javascript but think it might be something with how big of a number it is. Any help appreciated. Thanks :)

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
<script type="text/javascript">
 function twitterCallback(twitters) {
  var statusHTML = [];
  for (var i=0; i<twitters.length; i++){
    var username = twitters[i].user.screen_name;
    var status = twitters[i].text.replace(/((https?|s?ftp|ssh)\:\/\/[^"\s\<\>]*[^.,;'">\:\s\<\>\)\]\!])/g, function(url) {
       return '<a href="'+url+'" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">'+url+'</a>';
    }).replace(/\B@([_a-z0-9]+)/ig, function(reply) {
      return  reply.charAt(0)+'<a href="http://twitter.com/'+reply.substring(1)+'" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">'+reply.substring(1)+'</a>';
    });

    if(twitters[i].in_reply_to_screen_name){
        alert('http://twitter.com/'+twitters[i].in_reply_to_screen_name+'/status/'+twitters[i].in_reply_to_status_id);
    }
  }
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=PacSun&include_rts=true&count=15&callback=twitterCallback"></script>
```

Comment: *"I for the god of me could not figure out how to simply paste code"* You just indent the code with four spaces, as it says in the **How to Format** box to the right of the question area.

Comment: thanks, think I was already stressed from this error.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `in_reply_to_status_id_str` on the status object instead. Twitter's [Snowflake](http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/browse_thread/thread/6a16efa375532182?pli=1) status ID scheme produces values that are larger than the maximum integer value supported by Javascript and some JSON parsers. As a result of this, all numeric Twitter ID's that could have the potential of growing over 53 bits have `*_str` property complements.

From the linked document:

> ### The problem
>
> Before launch it came to our attention that some programming languages such 
>   as Javascript cannot support numbers
>   with >53bits. This can be easily 
>   examined by running a command similar
>   to: `(90071992547409921).toString()` in 
>   your browser's console or by running
>   the following JSON snippet through
>   your  JSON parser.
>
> ```
> {"id": 10765432100123456789, "id_str": "10765432100123456789"}
> ```
>
> In
>   affected JSON parsers the ID will not
>   be converted successfully and will 
>   lose accuracy. In some parsers there
>   may even be an exception.
>
> ### The solution
>
> To allow javascript and JSON parsers to read the IDs we
>   need to include a  string version of
>   any ID when responding in the JSON
>   format. What this means  is Status,
>   User, Direct Message and Saved Search
>   IDs in the Twitter API will  now be
>   returned as an integer and a string in
>   JSON responses. This will  apply to
>   the main Twitter API, the Streaming
>   API and the Search API.

Other links:

[What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a Number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/307179/210774)
[JavaScript 64 bit numeric precision](https://stackoverflow.com/q/506200/210774)
[What is the accepted way to send 64-bit values over JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/209869/210774)